DB2 SQL list single char values at positions specified in another table
Given two tables, i want to match values at certain position of the string in table two so that i can see how many produce does one student have:
Table1:



items
ids




apple
3


banana
4


carrot
1


tangerine
5


grape
2


melon
6


apple II
7



Table2:



Student
Items




Adam
'XXX12X5'


Eva
'X3XX16X'



(treat X as whitespace)
Expected result is to list number of items based on table2 and table1:



Column A
apple
banana
carrot
tangerine
grape
melon
apple II




Adam

1

2


5


Eva



1
3
6




Currently i check produce one by one using substring but i want to procedurally list all the items (i only added 7 items to simplify the problem, real table has string which is thousands of characters long)

Is this a homework question?

The way I would approach this is to create a procedure that receives the items field based on table 1, then select from table 2 and for each record pass the items field to your procedure.

With this SQL you can join data:
WITH
TABLE1(items, id) AS (VALUES ('apple', 3), ('banana', 4),
('carrot'   , 1),
('tangerine',   5),
('grape',   2),
('melon',   6),
('apple II',    7)
),

TABLE2(student, items) AS (VALUES ('Adam',  'XXX12X5'), ('Eva', 'X3XX16X'))


SELECT student, table1.items, replace(substr(table2.items, id, 1), 'X', '') FROM TABLE2 JOIN TABLE1 ON 1 =1     ;

This will be the result:
STUDENT ITEMS   00003
Adam    apple   
Eva apple   
Adam    banana  1
Eva banana  
Adam    carrot  
Eva carrot  
Adam    tangerine   2
Eva tangerine   1
Adam    grape   
Eva grape   3
Adam    melon   
Eva melon   6
Adam    apple II    5
Eva apple II    

Now you have only to transform from vertical to horizontal if needed
